# Jackson Error Unexpected character ('}' (code 125))

Tags: java, json, jackson

Hey i got an issue based on deserialization with jackson, here what i've tried and the error i got.

**ERROR** : com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('}' (code 125)): was expecting double-quote to start field name

**Java Code**

```
List<Contact> ds = mapper.readValue(data, mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Contact.class));

 //OR this one

List<Contact> ds = mapper.readValue(data, new TypeReference<List<Contact>>() {});
```

*My JSON*

```
[   
    {
        "id": "200",
        "name": "Alexia Milano",
        "email": "minalo@gmail.com",
        "prenom": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",

    }, {
        "id": "201",
        "name": "Johnny Depp",
        "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
        "prenom": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",

    }
]
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If you use [json validator](http://jsonlint.com/), you can see more detailed error message:

```
Parse error on line 6:
...ntry",            },    {        "id
---------------------^
Expecting 'STRING'
```

you have extra comma there after `"xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country"`. If you remove it from both two places, you have valid JSON and Jackson parsing works.

Comment: Thanks for the json validator tool. I used to only use jsbeautifer, but it was before.

Comment: the error was so misleading , i was lucky that I search google instead of debugging myself lol

Answer (score 15):

It's because your last entries, there is an `,` after your last value. Thats why jackson expects another field.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable ALLOW_TRAILING_COMMA (allowing a comma after the last value in an object or array), and then it parses it correctly, not having to modify the json and remove the comma:

```
jsonFactory.configure(JsonReadFeature.ALLOW_TRAILING_COMMA.mappedFeature(), true)
```